# Difference between vertical spacing system and baseline grid in digital design

Tags: typography, grids

What's the easiest way to explain the difference between vertical spacing system and baseline grid in digital design? By vertical spacing I understand distances between all elements on a web page and not only text.

Answer (score 1):

The baseline grid is used to maintain consistent horizontal "lines" across all the columns.

Vertical spacing is the amount of space between elements determined by the amount of space available; paper size and margins.

Combined they both help create a vertical rhythm.

A vertical rhythm is the structure that guides a reader’s eye through the content vertically, hence the name. This is used to create a fluid experience when scrolling through a webpage and is essential for a great web experience.